# Proof of divisibility by 18 by induction

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

I am trying to prove by induction that $7^n + 12n + 17$ is divisible by $18$.

The $n = 1$ case is clear, since $36$ is divisible by $m$. Then $7^n + 12n + 17 = 18m$ for some integer $m$. Then I need to show that $7^{n+1} + 12(n+1) + 17$ is divisible by $18$, but I can't figure out how to do this. Expanding it out, I get $7^{n+1} + 12n + 29$. I want to take out a factor of $7$ and use the induction hypothesis. So I considered adding and subtracting $72n$ to form $84n$, from which I can pull out a factor of $7$, and similarly $17 \cdot 12 = 204$. I can't get the remaining constant factor to work out, though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $7(7^{n}+12n+17)-72n-90=7^{n+1}+12n+29+72n$

Comment: $(6+1)^n\equiv 1+6n$, so $7^n+12n+17\equiv0\pmod{18}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the inductive step fix some $n$, assume that $7^n+12n+17$ is divisible by $18$, and use:
$$
\begin{aligned}
7^{n+1}+12(n+1)+17
&= 7(7^n+12n+17) -72 n-90\\
&= 7(7^n+12n+17) - 18(4n+5)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
It is assumed that $7^n\equiv -12n+1\pmod{18}$ by the induction, so
$$7^{n+1}+12(n+1)+17\equiv 7(6n+1)+12(n+1)+17\pmod{18}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**\begin{align}7^{n+1}+12(n+1)+17-(7^n+12n+17)&=6\times7^n+12\\&=6((6+1)^n+2)\end{align}and $(6+1)^n+2$ can be written as $6k+3$, for some integer $k$.